# How I get the right Data from my Column with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, datatable

I not so good in Linq and I want to make a query to get the right data. I have a Datatable with this columns :

[image]

I want to get in the datatable by the Columns TIMEFROM and TIMETO get this = 10.12.2012
 not 10.12.2012 00:00:00.

How I can do this: the name of my datatable is table.

```
MySqlCommand selectcommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlcommand, connection);

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectcommand);

                DataTable table = new DataTable(TABLE);


                adapter.Fill(table);

                table = table.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("Activate") == 1).CopyToDataTable();



                //i need the shorter form 



                connection.Open();

                selectcommand.ExecuteReader();

                return table;
```

Comment: what do you mean by the columns? Do you want just the dates and to shorten them or the whole table ordered by the time from time to?

Comment: think the image is not uploaded properly.

Comment: to omit the hour from a DateTime object, use .ToString("d")

Comment: better would be myVar.ToShortDateString()

Comment: Once you have the data: dateTime = dateTime.ToShortDateString();

Comment: Both are [identical](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx).

Comment: I get the data from a mysql database and the form is yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use

```
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", dataTable.Rows[0]["TIMEFROM"]);
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", dataTable.Rows[0]["TIMETO"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create contextclass than create object before you can run the linq command on it. 
For example your table name is test than you create Linq to Sql class file, drag table test on it. 
Than on your main program or where ever you need to call it.

```
      testContext ct=new testContext();
      var er=from e in ct.test 
      Select new(e.TIMEFROM, e.TIMETO);
```